# In Linux, is there a way to keep the output of the jobs command showing for a set amount of time ?

Tags: linux, jobs

I have some trouble when running the following `jobs` command, because  it only shows jobs that have been completed (marked with "Done" ) for a brief amount of time. The following screenshot demonstrates this .  Where is this configuration set ?

[image]

i.e after a job goes from "running" to "done", I would like it show the "Done" line for at least 5 minutes .

Comment: You can only see once `Done`. Put it to a variable if you wanna store it.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job.  Use notifications for that kind of things.

Comment: @IporSircer - Ok I see ,  How to put into a variable?